# How to implement global VB6 error handler?

Tags: vb6, error-handling

The global VB6 error handler product referred to in the following link claims to "install a small callback hook into the VBE6 debugger":

http://www.everythingaccess.com/simplyvba/globalerrorhandler/howitworks.htm

I would like to implement this product myself because I would like more control over what it is doing.  How is the above product likely to be achieving what it does?

Comment: We might be able to answer the question in your title, but not the question in your last sentence; it is too broad.

Comment: Sounds a little scary to me. Hooks in VB6 can cause the IDE to crash if not handled correctly. And what happens if you have one or more procedures where you want to handle the errors yourself? Is that still possible or does this hook steal all errors without exceptions?

Comment: @Martin: It's a VBA only tool

Comment: No, the site linked has VB6 content too.  I've used instrumenting tools that decorate your source with the infrastructure to support this kind of functionality, but it is not clear to me what mechanism is being used here.

Comment: There is no VBA mentioned in the Question. Tags and content suggest this question is about VB6.

Answer (score 1):

The product you are looking at is a COM component. From the [documentation](http://www.everythingaccess.com/simplyvba/globalerrorhandler/installation_vb6.htm) that is available on the web site, it sounds like the COM component implements particular component classes. The first thing to do, if you already have the product, would be to fire up SysInternals `procmon`, run `regsvr32` on the DLL, and figure out what component classes are implemented from the registry entries that are created. Once you know this, MSDN may be able to tell you what interfaces correspond to those component classes.

Microsoft developed a framework called Active Scripting that allows you to host a script engine and inject debugging capabilities. If one assumes that VB6 produces an exe that ties into that framework, you *might* be able to do:

- Create a COM component that implements `IApplicationDebugger`
- Implement `IApplicationDebugger::onHandleBreakPoint` to be able to respond to errors in the VB code
- Read MSDN KB [Q222966](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222966) to find out how to call back to VB from `onHandleBreakPoint`

It looks like the product injects the `ErrEx` class using `IActiveScript::AddNamedItem`. To provide the same behaviour, Implement `IActiveScriptSite::GetItemInfo` on the same COM component to return a pointer to an instance of (and the associated `TypeInfo` for) a COM component that implements the same interface as `ErrEx`. In your implementation of `ErrEx.EnableGlobalErrorHandler` you would do the following:

- `CoCreateInstance` inproc Process Debug Manager
- Cast reference to `IRemoteDebugApplication`
- Register an instance of your `IApplicationDebugger` component using `IRemoteDebugApplication::ConnectDebugger`

I glossed over calling `IActiveScript::AddNamedItem` because I have no idea how you get a pointer to `IActiveScript` from a running process. Also, I don't know if creating a new instance of the Process Debug Manager will work, or if you somehow have to hook into an existing instance.

I apologize for the confusing explanation, missing information, and glossing over large parts of the process, but this is going waaay back...

You will want to read the [Active Scripting APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301316.aspx) article at MSDN.